# invoke code after all queued events are processed

Tags: c++, qt

I have two functions: `myCode1()` and `myCode2()`. I have very little control over what is in `myCode1()` (will be implemented by other party), it can be almost anything, within some sane limits, of course. I need to call first `myCode1()` and only after it is "finished" I need to call `myCode2()`, which implementation I have in full control. By "finished" I mean when all synchronous code is done and event loop is done processing all events which were created as the result of `myCode1()`.

My first try was trivial:

```
myCode1();
myCode2();
```

But there is a trouble that when `myCode1()` opens dialog with its own event loop (`QDialog::exec()`), then `myCode2()` is called only after the dialog is closed, which is not what I need. I need to call `myCode2()` after the dialog gets open and is waiting for users interaction.

So my second try:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, []{ myCode2(); });
myCode1();
```

This is slightly better because it schedules `myCode2()` to be processed by event loop after `myCode1()` does its synchronous work, i.e. after the potential dialog with blocking event loop gets opened.

But there is yet another problem. `myCode1()` can create lots of posted events in event queue and I need them to be processed before actually before calling `myCode2()`. But with the way show above, these events are queued after scheduled `myCode2()`.

So what I would actually need is to schedule `myCode2` after ALL events are done including posted events, i.e. when the event loop is empty. And it should work also in the presence of blocking dialogs etc.

I also tried `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` but these events can post more events and enqueue them at the end of the queue... Moreover `QCodeApplication::hasPendingEvents()` is marked as deprecated so it cannot help to check whether event queue is empty. Otherwise my implementation would look like this:

```
void myCode2()
{
  while (QCoreApplication::hasPendingEvents())
  { 
    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
  }
  doMyCode2(); // this would do the actual code
}
```

And I would schedule it with the `QTimer` as above. But as I wrote, `hasPendingEvents()` is deprecated... so I am in bad luck.

Any ideas how to achieve what I need to achieve? I hope there is some simple solution which I just overlooked.

PS: To clarify the purpose - `myCode2()` should inform about the state of the application. And I need to inform about "final" or "stable" state. Which means that if there are yet more events to be processed, the state is not finished nor stable. Therefore I need to process all events first, including events which were created by previous events.

Comment: I would check the author/implementation of `myCode1` to see if there is some kind of `finished` signal you can hook `myCode2` onto. Otherwise there is no clean solution.

Comment: Nope, there is not such a signal. And even if there was, I could not be sure that there are not more posted events after this in the event loop.

Comment: So `myCode1` is a blocking call, but you want `myCode2` to run after `myCode1` finishes just PART of its tasks? Without a signal from `myCode1`, the best you can do is use a timer with a long enough timeout that you can guess (but not guarantee) it's safe to call `myCode2`.

Comment: Yeah, now I am using exactly what you are suggesting. `QTimer::singleShot()` with long enough delay (500 ms in my case) so that all possible events are processed. But I am not very happy with this solution, I was looking for something less arbitrary.